# Cannot login as root user in ssh

Tags: linux, centos5, root

I create an user with root prevelages in my server. 
Now i cannot login into the server as root through ssh. 
Also I cannot access the vi editor through the new user login.

Comment: Please help me before you going to down vote.

Comment: Server Fault is a site for system and network administrators needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a professional capacity.  Please read this page before posting again: http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now i cannot login into the server as root through ssh.

This is the default for CentOS. Edit the /etc/ssh/sshd_config and remove the comment from the "PermitRootLogin yes" directive. Restart the sshd server. Remember, enabling root login is a bad idea, unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Error reading /etc/ssh/sshd_config: Permission denied ] this is the error when i try to open sshd_config

Comment: I think you need a "Quick and Dirty Guide To Basic Linux Administration". Google around, there are hundreds of books, howto, FAQ, and so on.

Comment: could you help me how to login as root user again ? now the access denied. i neet to login into yhe system as root for some modifications. thats why i asked?

Comment: I manage 10 remote CentOS installations in this way: ssh using a standard user (non-root). Then I do a "su -" command. It will ask you the password for the root user. If the password is valid, you become root.

Comment: i need to install phpmyadmin. but it need root login for activation.

Comment: Not to be rude, but since you do not know the bare basics of systems administrations, I would strongly advise against installing PHPmyadmin right now. You need to first learn the basics. Otherwise you can expect to have your system compromised in short order.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have **PermitRootLogin no** in your sshd configuration.

Comment: no i didn't. still its
#PermitRootLogin Yes

Comment: Remove the leading '#'

Comment: it is commented out - still remote root logins are a bad idea

Comment: Error reading /etc/ssh/sshd_config: Permission denied ] this is the error when i try to open sshd_config

Comment: you will need root level access to modify the file.

Comment: @ManeeshMohanachandran - it sounds like you need to read a Linux 101 webpage to at least learn the basics of the OS first

Comment: @ManeeshMohanachandran You can't edit that file, or restart the ssh service, without having root privileges...

Comment: You aren't root. Switch to root user.

Comment: i cannot switch to root user. The access is denied. how to enable it again?

Comment: If you can, su, or use sudo.  If you can't, use the local console.  Failing that, you've locked yourself out.

Answer (score 0):

Terribly worded question, shows no research or attempt to help yourself - thoroughly deserves closing immediately.

That said have you looked in /etc/ssh/sshd_config for a line saying "PermitRootLogin no", if it's there then change it to 'yes' and do a "/etc/init.d/sshd restart" to make the change come into effect.

Oh and don't post again until you've read our FAQ, instead of skipping it, and therefore know what we expect of question askers ok.

Comment: i didn't change that part still its #PermitRootLogin Yes

Comment: The # means that the line is commented out, i.e. not in effect.